# only allow integer using validate.js

Tags: jquery, validation

i m using validate.js.

```
 var v = $("#form1").validate({
                    ignore: ':hidden',
                    rules: {
                        txtName: { required: true },
                        txtTitle: { required: true }
                        txtInterval:{///Only allow integer}

                    },
                    messages: {
                        txtName: "<br/>Please enter a Name",
                        txtTitle: "<br/>Please enter a Title",
                        txtInterval:"<br/>Please Enter a Integer"
                    }
                });
```

Code Works fine i want to validate `txtInterval` which allow only integer value but don't know how to do this through `validate.js.Show me a correct way.`Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    field: {
      required: true,
      number: true
    }
  }
});
```

[Read Documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/number)